Do we accept screen caps that include ads?
Do we accept screen caps that include ads?
Context: Lego Modulars Massive Inflation?
This seems less than ideal to me, but it is enough of a border case I wanted to see if it was just me before asking the question asker to edit the images down to something more salient.

I do not think it is a problem if ads are included as part of a screenshot of a website and they do not take up a significant portion of the image. 
In this particular case the advert (and even the status bar at the top of the page) can be cropped out very easily as they do not contribute to the illustration in any meaningful way, at least based on the context of the post.
I have cropped and resized the images used in that post.
